# LoadModel or Tableregistry CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

When i use Tableregistry PHPStorm detects all the methods,

but when i use LoadModel CakePHP does not find any method for example toArray().

Im kind of a maniac when it refers to errors in the IDE, is there any declaration to be made or something, i know it is better to use load model than using tableregistry, or i least thats what i read on other anwers

```
Method 'toArray' not found in less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Referenced method is not found in subject class.
```

Comment: You can add `@property \App\Model\Table\PostsTable $Posts` annotation lines above your model class, especially if you have multiple of those loadModel() calls in your class. Otherwise you can stick to the inline solution offered below.

Answer (score 1):

You can add single line DocComment above your `loadModel()` calls similar to

`/** @property \App\Model\Table\PostsTable $Posts */`

Comment: Should actually be the other way around: \Class $var. as it is with all doc blocks. But both work in most IDEs.